# How can I share SQL 2014 database to my friends?

Tags: sql, database

I heard it is possible to do it the online method by connecting to it. However I am unsure of it. Is there any other possible methods? Thank you.

Comment: By "SQL 2014" do you mean SQL Server 2014?

Comment: Yes, SQL Server 2014. The database